# Opentok 2.6 iOS framework issue, blank screen issue while changing application state

Tags: screen, opentok, tokbox

I am facing random issue with tokbox framework in my iOS app, when I put my application in background and come to foreground multiple times during my video session, sometimes video gets stuck and I see blank screen, while audio always remains there.

I am setting publisher as well as subscriber video NO while going to background and YES when coming to foreground.

What could be the case?

Answer (score 0):

The background modes flag need to be set , so that the OpenTok session persists. Specifically make sure that yourApp -> Capabilities -> Background Modes -> Audio & Airplay flag is on. (In Xcode 7 it is the Audio,Airplay and Picture in Picture flag)

You can understand more about how tokbox functions in the background mode at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html. For your case look at the setting app permissions section.